# Scheduling smart home Actions

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I can set up scheduled actions by saying "**OK google, turn on bedroom in 10 minutes**", but how can i cancel this scheduling ?

"**OK google, cancel my scheduled actions**"

google says "**I'm still not getting it, so let's stop for now.**"

could you please guide ?

** User can add voice schedules, but there is no way to either "show all scheduled actions" or "cancel my scheduled actions" can be performed,
The official documentation is incomplete and have insufficient information i think, or feature is still not fully developed/deployed i think,

Could anyone please guide if i am missing something, or is there any recent status on this feature.

Thanks
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

thanks for reporting this. I was able to reproduce the the same error message too. I've submitted a bug internally to correct this. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any update on this?? @Jessica Earley-Cha